# Recommendations for a multi-language spell checking control for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, multilingual, spell-checking

Looking for recommendations for a control which make can do spell checking for various languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out the NetSpell as it is free first:

http://www.loresoft.com/projects/netspell/default.aspx

Here is a quick description:

> The NetSpell project is a spell
>   checking engine written entirely in
>   managed C# .net code.  NetSpell's
>   suggestions for a misspelled word are
>   generated using phonetic (sounds like)
>   matching and ranked by a typographical
>   (looks like) score.  NetSpell supports
>   multiple languages and the
>   dictionaries are based on the
>   OpenOffice Affix compression format.
>   The library can be used in Windows or
>   Web Form projects. The download
>   includes an English dictionary with
>   dictionaries for other languages
>   available for download on the project
>   web site. NetSpell also supports user
>   added words and automatic creation of
>   user dictionaries. It also includes a
>   dictionary build tool to build custom
>   dictionaries.

If you want a good one that is not free I would recomment KarmaSoft UltimateSpell:

http://www.aspnetspellchecker.com/UltimateSpell/Features.aspx

> Top 10 Features of Karamasoft
>   UltimateSpell for ASP.NET
>
> 1. Spell check as you type
> 2. Grammar check and synonyms
> 3. Spell check TEXT and HTML
> 4. Spell 1500 words per second
> 5. Auto correct misspelled words
> 6. Auto find all editable areas
> 7. Lookup online dictionary
> 8. 34 dictionaries for free
> 9. Add to custom dictionary
> 10. Windows Forms support

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Telerik RadSpell:

http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/spell.aspx

Answer (score 0):

We use UltimateSpell.   Price is very reasonable and has a clean/easy to use interface.

http://www.karamasoft.com/ultimatespell/features.aspx

Comment: I already had that in my answer with the exact link and all :P

Answer (score 0):

Hunspell works well, and the price is right - free!